# Velocity of bullet-block system

Tags: free-fall

If a bullet is fired at a certain speed and hits (and is embedded on) a block at the edge of a cliff causing it to fall, will the initial velocity of the bullet-block system have any effect to the velocity it takes before it hits the ground? (I assume that it does not have any effect since its purely horizontal velocity).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the horizontal velocity component still counts towards the velocity. So, no matter the axis of collision, the velocity right before hitting the ground will be greater due to the collision.

If the collision happens on the $x$ axis, then the final $y$-velocity component of the bullet-block system will be the same with/or without collision.

Comment: In this case, the collision occurs only on the $x$ axis. Thus, in getting their final velocity, I only had to use $\sqrt{2gh}$, regardless of how big the horizontal velocity component was.

Comment: The vertical ($y$) velocity will be indeed $\sqrt{2gh}$. It might still have a horizontal projection too, so the total velocity $\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$ will be larger.